# ASP.NET Core application deployed on Azure cannot logout(received 302) on one of the environments

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, http-status-code-302

We have deployed the application on 3 environments: DEV, QA and UAT. On DEV and UAT everything is going well, but on QA the logout is not possible: it returns "302 Found" and redirect to the home page without logging it out.

The environments have different databases. DEV and QA use the same Azure B2C.

This is the result of the .well-known/openid-configuration (I've replaced the original url with localhost):

{
"issuer":"localhost/auth",
"jwks_uri":"localhost/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/endsession",
"check_session_iframe":"localhost/auth/connect/checksession",
"revocation_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/revocation",
"introspection_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/introspect",
"device_authorization_endpoint":"localhost/auth/connect/deviceauthorization",
"frontchannel_logout_supported":true,
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,
"backchannel_logout_supported":true,
"backchannel_logout_session_supported":true,
"scopes_supported":[
"openid",
"profile",
"email",
"pws",
"djs",
"sep",
"offline_access"
],
"claims_supported":[
"sub",
"updated_at",
"locale",
"zoneinfo",
"birthdate",
"gender",
"website",
"profile",
"preferred_username",
"nickname",
"middle_name",
"given_name",
"family_name",
"name",
"picture",
"email_verified",
"email",
"organizations",
"CouponCodes",
"nameid"
],
"grant_types_supported":[
"authorization_code",
"client_credentials",
"refresh_token",
"implicit",
"password",
"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
],
"response_types_supported":[
"code",
"token",
"id_token",
"id_token token",
"code id_token",
"code token",
"code id_token token"
],
"response_modes_supported":[
"form_post",
"query",
"fragment"
],
"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[
"client_secret_basic",
"client_secret_post"
],
"subject_types_supported":[
"public"
],
"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[
"RS256"
],
"code_challenge_methods_supported":[
"plain",
"S256"
],
"request_parameter_supported":true
}

Thank you for any suggestion about how to investigate this 302 response.

Comment: We're going to need more information to be able to help. In its current form, this is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask].

Comment: Thanks @rickvdbosch for your message. The thing is that I don't know what other information to share.